# How to set HeaderTemplate Property of HeaderedContentControl Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, header

I am working in WPF and I need to set the Text and ToolTip of a **Header** of a HeaderedContentControl. So what I am trying to do is to create a template as below:

```
 System.Windows.DataTemplate template = new System.Windows.DataTemplate();
 template.DataType = typeof(HeaderedContentControl);

 System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory blockFactory = new System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
 blockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "The Header Text");
 blockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "The ToolTip");

 template.VisualTree = blockFactory;

 myHeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate = template;
```

But when I run the program the header is displayed empty. What am I doing wrong?

Hope someone can help, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have no idea why do you use template in a such way. Why not just set header property with the text block?

```
myHeaderedContentControl.Header = new TextBlock 
{
    Text = "Some text", 
    ToolTip = "Some tooltip"
};
```

Moreover, it is even better idea to define all that in XAML:

```
<HeaderedContentControl x:Name="control">
    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Some text" ToolTip="Some tooltip"/>
    </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually that was my first try, but an error raises which tells me that I cannot set an element to the header, instead of that I should use the HeaderTemplate

Comment: No way, I tried all examples before posting. Should work perfectly in .net4. What version of .net do you use? Could you provide mentioned error message?